# Change text value in html after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I create a button with append

```
var row = '<tr><td><button class="directly-follow btn" text="Follow">Follow</button></td></tr>';
$('.textWord_about> table > tbody').append(row);
```

I want to change the button text using jquery, by clicking on the button.

This is what am I doing:

```
$(document).on('click', '.directly-follow', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $post = $(this);
    if ($post.attr("text") == "Follow") {
        $post.text('Unfollow');
        //do something
     }
     else{
        $post.text('Follow');
        //do something
     }
```

the problem is that the line `$post.text('Unfollow')` changes the button text but it does not change the defined text in the html tag(`text="Follow"`). As a result, the functionality does not toggle as I want.(the if is always true!).

How can change the text using jquery?

Comment: You have a typo in `$('.textWord_about'> table > tbody').append(row);` (extra `'`). And `text` isn't a valid attribute for the button element

Comment: As @j08691 said, remove the `'` immediately after `textWord_about`

Comment: @j08691 actually, append is not the problem. I have made the code a little simpler in the question and I just forgot to omit the extra ' .

Comment: I didn't say it was the problem, I said your extra `'` was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value of a custom `attribute` you have to use `attr` method.

`attr` method can be used in order to get the `attribute` value, but also to set the `attribute` value.

> The method gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or sets one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.directly-follow', function() {
event.preventDefault();
var $post = $(this);
if ($post.attr("text") == "Follow") {
    $post.text('Unfollow');
    $post.attr('text','Unfollow');
 }
 else{
    $post.text('Follow');
    $post.attr('text','Follow');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attr instead of text.
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```js
var row = '<tr><td><button class="directly-follow btn" text="Follow">Follow</button></td></tr>';

$('.textWord_about> table > tbody').append(row);

$(document).on('click', '.directly-follow', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("text") == "Follow") {
      $(this).text('Unfollow');
      $(this).attr('text','Unfollow');
   }
   else{
      $(this).text('Follow');
      $(this).attr('text','Follow');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textWord_about">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd11nyfy/3/)

```js
var row = '<tr><td><button class="directly-follow btn" text="Follow">Follow</button></td></tr>';
$('.textWord_about> table > tbody').append(row);

$(document).on('click', '.directly-follow', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $post = $(this);
    console.log($post.attr("text"))
    if ($post.attr("text") == "Follow") {
        $post.text('Unfollow');
    $post.attr("text","Unfollow")
        //do something
     }
     else{
        $post.text('Follow');
    $post.attr("text","Follow")
        //do something
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='textWord_about'>
  <table>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class='directly-follow'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to retreive a custom attribute (which should begin with "data-").

Then, a button has no `text()`... But has `html()`, for the text displayed on it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.directly-follow', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $post = $(this);
  if ($post.data("text") == "Follow") {
    $post.html('Unfollow');
    $post.data("text","Unfollow");
    //do something
  }
  else{
    $post.html('Follow');
    $post.data("text","Follow");
    //do something
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="directly-follow btn" data-text="Follow">Follow</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```